# ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword when i tried to insert multiple rows in Oracle database table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to insert multiple rows in the oracle table but getting the following error

```
ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
```

Following are my insert statements

```
INSERT ALL
      into COUNTRY ("CountryID","CountryName") values (1,'Germany')
      into COUNTRY ("CountryID","CountryName") values (2,'United Kingdom')
      into COUNTRY ("CountryID","CountryName") values (3,'United States')
      into COUNTRY ("CountryID","CountryName") values (4,'Russia')
      into COUNTRY ("CountryID","CountryName") values (5,'France')
      into COUNTRY ("CountryID","CountryName") values (6,'Pakistan')
      into COUNTRY ("CountryID","CountryName") values (7,'India')
      into COUNTRY ("CountryID","CountryName") values (8,'Brazil')
      into COUNTRY ("CountryID","CountryName") values (9,'Itly')
      into COUNTRY ("CountryID","CountryName") values (10,'Iran'),
      into COUNTRY ("CountryID","CountryName") values (11,'Austria')
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleted one "coma":

```
INSERT ALL
      into COUNTRY ("CountryID","CountryName") values (1,'Germany')
      into COUNTRY ("CountryID","CountryName") values (2,'United Kingdom')
      into COUNTRY ("CountryID","CountryName") values (3,'United States')
      into COUNTRY ("CountryID","CountryName") values (4,'Russia')
      into COUNTRY ("CountryID","CountryName") values (5,'France')
      into COUNTRY ("CountryID","CountryName") values (6,'Pakistan')
      into COUNTRY ("CountryID","CountryName") values (7,'India')
      into COUNTRY ("CountryID","CountryName") values (8,'Brazil')
      into COUNTRY ("CountryID","CountryName") values (9,'Itly')
      into COUNTRY ("CountryID","CountryName") values (10,'Iran')
      into COUNTRY ("CountryID","CountryName") values (11,'Austria')
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
```